# how to send a form data to server using post api in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

how can I send form data using post API using angular , have used form and method for component.ts file ,

```
<form #hlForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="getHospitalList(hlForm)">
  <input 
   type="text" 
   class="input-texts" 
   name="name" 
   placeholder="Enter Hospital , Insurance or Location"
   ngModel
   required
  >
  <button 
  type="submit" 
  value="submit" 
  class="hl-btn"
  (click)="hospitalFirstFold = false; hospitalSecondFold = true;"
   >Search
   </button>
</form>

  getHospitalList(form){
    console.log(form.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to create form data to send data using post api.

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append(key, value);
```

For api call

```
this.http.post(url, fd);
```

> Fill values accordingly in formdata

Comment: Are there any constraints on what value should be? Must it be form.value or can it be anything like string or number?

Comment: Value refers to what is required in the api. For ex: fd.append('age', '24').. Now this 24 might be coming from your some formControl or ngModel. I hope you can relate it now?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a service file.
2. Create one function named of your choice, for example, function1 in your class.

```
function1(formData) {
return this.http.post(url, formData);
}
```

Add http in the constructor and import it.

```
constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}
```

3. Call that function1 in your class with form as a parameter and subscribe

```
   getHospitalList() {
    this.serviceA.function1(form.value).subscribe(response) => 
      {console.log(response)});
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Start by importing the necessary APIs:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Declare submit function like below:

```
getHospitalList(form){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('key', form.value);

    this.httpClient.post<any>(this.SERVER_URL, formData).subscribe(
      (res) => console.log(res),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import HttpClientModule and formsmodule in your app module if you have not defined a different module.

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

*in your component*
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

add serverurl as :
private readonly baseUrl = 'YourUrl';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

create a method you gonna use for your submit event from your for ""

  getHospitalList(form: NgForm) {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl, form.value).subscribe(next => {
      console.log("successful");
    },
    error => {
      console.log("failed submitting");
    });
  }

(click)="hospitalFirstFold = false; hospitalSecondFold = true;" what is going on there??
```

Comment: (click)="hospitalFirstFold = false; hospitalSecondFold = true;" what is going on there??

Comment: this for pagination, for sections, sorry for the confusion, it is unrelated to this part